# get values from a text file with a mix of floats and strings

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with a text file that I have to read in. In this file, there are two types of line:

- `133 0102764447 44 11 54 0.4 0 0.89 0 0 8 0  0 7  Attribute_Name='xyz' Type='string' 02452387764447 884`
- `134 0102256447 44 1 57 0.4 0 0.81 0 0 8 0  0 1  864`

What I want to do here is to textscan all the lines and then try to determine the number of 'xyz' (and the total number of lines).

I tried to use:

```
fileID = fopen('test.txt','r') ;
data=textscan(fileID, %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %d %d','\n) ;
```

And then I will try to access data{i,16} to count how many are equal to Attribute_Name='xyz', it doesnt seem to be an efficient though.

what will be a proper way to read the data(what interests me is to count how many Attribute_Name='xyz' do I have)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `count` which is referenced [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/count.html).

In your case you could use it in this way:

```
filetext = fileread("test.txt");
A = count(filetext , "xyz")
```

`fileread` will read the whole text file into a single string. Afterwards you can process that string using `count` which will return the occurrences from the given pattern.

Comment: I am using matlab 2012b, the function count is undefined. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

An alternative when using older versions of MATLAB is this one. It will work with `R2006a` and above.

```
filetext = fileread("test.txt");
A = length(strfind(filetext, "xyz");
```

[`strfind`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) will return an array which length represents the amount of occurrences of the specified string. The length of that array can be accessed by [`length`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is the option of `strsplit`. You may do something like the following:

```
count = 0;
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');
while ~feof(fid)
   line = fgetl(fid);
   words = strsplit( line )
   ind = find( strcmpi(words{:},'Attribute_Name=''xyz'''), 1);  % Assume only one instance per line, remove 1 for more and correct the rest of the code
   if ( ind > 0 ) then
      count = count + 1;
   end if
end
```

So at the end `count` will give you the number.